# Typesafe Activator : Evolutions : unable to display 1.sql?

Tags: playframework-2.0, slick, playframework-evolutions, typesafe-activator

Googling didn't help, therefore I'm tying here now.  I haven't had much success with Activator 1.0.0 so far.  For example, I stumble on the following issue, both on Windows and on Linux (Ubuntu 13.04 64bit), when "playing" with the "play-slick" template (and with others too), just trying to follow the tutorial.

Whether I create the 1.sql evolution script within Activator ("Code" > "+" > "New file") or outside of it has no impact, Activator ("Code" tab) always gives the same error message : "Unable to display: <path_to_projects>/play-slick/conf/evolutions/default/1.sql".

This is not my only problem but let's start with this one.  At first, under Windows, I suspected that it might have something to do with associations between applications and file extensions but the same happens under Linux.  And if I change the extension (say, to 1.sql.txt or 1.txt), just as a try, it does not help (same error : unable to display). I cannot see anything relevant in the logs.

All in all, Activator is a nice idea but apparently it still has some toothaches.

Thanks for any help.

Best regards,

Comment: This is a bug where `.sql` is not mapped to a renderable file format in Activator.  I've filed a bug for this: https://github.com/typesafehub/activator/issues/106

Comment: Thank you, James.  That's a point but that doesn't explain why substituting, say "1.sql.txt" to "1.sql" leads to the same behavior (or does it in view of the bug) ?

Comment: How are you substituting that new name?

Comment: By deleting the .sql file from within Activator and creating a new one named "1.sql.txt" in Activator too.  IIRC, I also tried by creating the file outside of Activator and trying to open it from within but there was no difference.

Comment: Ah.  This is a bug.  I've filed it: https://github.com/typesafehub/activator/issues/113

Answer (score 0):

This should be working in Activator 1.0.10: http://downloads.typesafe.com/typesafe-activator/1.0.10/typesafe-activator-1.0.10.zip